# Integral Calculus - Difficulty solving question, distance travelled after 2.5 minutes

Tags: calculus

Based on an experiment lasting 2.5 minutes, the velocity of a body travelling in a medium may be modelled by the equation
$$
\mathrm{}\left(\right) = −0.2^{2} + 0.7 + 0.5\ {\mbox{m} \over \mbox{min}}\,,\qquad  \mbox{m: } 
$$
where $t$ is the number of minutes from the start position.

i. Find the position function $\mathrm{D}\left(t\right)$ that the body has moved from the start position.

I've struggling a little and not quite sure if I've done this correct. Think have correct formula below. I need to find the distance travelled in meters from 0 to $2.5$ mins.

When I transpose $t = 2.5$ into the equation I'm not entirely sure it's correct! Grateful any help on how to find this annoying me answer.enter image description here

[Formula used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvH0E.jpg)

Comment: What is your formula?  What did you get at $t=2.5$?

Comment: I did paste a attachment of my formula, just noticed not  part of the question.

Comment: Your integration is correct.  I would set this up as a definite integral with bound of 0 and 2.5, rather than as an indefinite integral.... but that just means that $C=0$ in this case....

Comment: Now what your suggesting is where I kinda come upstuck.  If I response t=2.5 into the formula, the results come out with some very strange numbers (Eg: 2.5^3 - 15.625), just horrendous numbers.  I don't this is correct!!!

Comment: 15.625 is  a perfectly fine number.  What makes you think that your answer should be an integer, or a fraction with small numerator and denominator,  or something with a small decimal expansion?

Comment: That's kinda where I've come unstuck.  Numbers I'm inputting 15.625/15 + 43.75/20 +2.5/2, then I'm trying to reduce to small denominators/fractions isn't working particular well.  Any ideas thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are in calculus you really should be able to work with fractions.

$-(\frac {1}{5})(\frac 13)(\frac {5}{2})^3 + (\frac {7}{10})(\frac 12)(\frac {5}{2})^2 + (\frac 12)(\frac 52)\\
-\frac {25}{24}+\frac {35}{16} + \frac {5}{4}$

Looks like $48$ would be the common denominator.

$\frac {-50 + 105+ 60}{48} = \frac {115}{48}$

Or, if you want to do this all in decimal...

$(-0.1046\bar6)+(2.1875)+(1.25) = 2.3958\bar3$

And to convert from decimal to fractional.  I would suggest we separate out the integer part and multiplying the tail by $\frac {3}{3}$

$2+\frac 13(1.1875)$  Now we have a finite decimal.  You might even recognize it as $\frac {19}{16}.$  Otherwise you could say $\frac {11875}{10000}$ and reduce.

$2\frac {19}{48}$

Comment: Hi, really appreciate the help you have given.  From your workings you saying the distance travelled in 2.5 minutes is 2 19/48.  2.4meters I make it!